# HTTP request caputure (hidden)

Tags: http, browser

I am trying to analyse http posts and get requests made to google finance.

I use `Fiddler` to view requests, but I don't understand how the real time quotes data has been transferred, as there are no calls made to the server.

Comment: fiddler and mozila browser inspect element and httpfox

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].

Comment: any one please help

Comment: still not able to get the data...